# Node / MySQL: Insert only works first time

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, insert

I'm having an issue with node (currently v6) and mysql.

`Node Code` is being run server side and not getting any errors.  The code works the first time; however, subsequent times the `name` and `description` values are entered as an empty string, and the `quantity` column as `0` (default value).

`created`,`pid`, and `id` (auto-incremented) columns' values are inserted correctly.  I'm not sure why this is working fine the first time, and not working afterwards.

edit:  When I take the outputted query from `addMany` and input it directly into mysql, it works every time.

How do I get this working correctly every time? Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `created` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `k_pid` (`pid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_some_table_p_pid` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `p` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1337 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Node Code:

```
function addMany(items, callback) {
    const itemsArray = Array.isArray(items) ? items : [items];
    const params = itemsArray.map((item) => {
        return [
            item.pid,
            item.quantity,
            item.name,
            item.description,
            Math.floor(new Date() / 1000),
        ];
    });

    const queryStr = 'INSERT INTO some_table (`pid`, `quantity`, `name`, `description`, `created`)  VALUES ?;';
    db.executeQuery(queryStr, [params], callback);
}
```

First Run:

```
const items1 = [ 
    { name: 'name__1', description: 'some desc 1', quantity: 1, pid: '17771' },
    { name: 'name__2', description: 'some desc 2', quantity: 1, pid: '17771' } 
];
addMany(items1, () => {});
```

`addMany` creates and runs this query:

```
INSERT INTO some_table 
    (`pid`, `quantity`, `name`, `description`, `created`)  
VALUES 
    ('17771', 1, 'name__1', 'some desc 1', 1502913412), 
    ('17771', 1, 'name__2', 'some desc 2', 1502913412);
```

MYSQL show this data:

```
id      pid             quantity        name        description     created
6423    17771           1               name__1     some desc 1     1502913412
6424    17771           1               name__2     some desc 2     1502913412
```

Second Run:

```
const items2 = [ 
    { name: 'name__3', description: 'some desc 3', quantity: 1, pid: '17771' },
    { name: 'name__4', description: 'some desc 4', quantity: 1, pid: '17771' } 
];
addMany(items2, () => {});
```

`addMany` creates and runs this query:

```
INSERT INTO some_table 
    (`pid`, `quantity`, `name`, `description`, `created`)  
VALUES 
    ('17771', 1, 'name__3', 'some desc 3', 1502913412), 
    ('17771', 1, 'name__4', 'some desc 4', 1502913412);
```

MYSQL show this data:

```
id      pid             quantity        name        description     created
6423    17771           1               name__1     some desc 1     1502913412
6424    17771           1               name__2     some desc 2     1502913412
6425    17771           0                                           1502913412
6426    17771           0                                           1502913412
```

Comment: The query which you display for `addMany`, looks OK, however how did you get the query string for this question? Because it looks like the query string displayed is not the one which is running.

Comment: I'm using the npm module `mysql` which converts a param array into the appropriate mysql syntax.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, however to verify the query: Did you get the query from logging or did you type the query as stated here (at second run) yourself? Because the query looks good and I think if you manually test that in MySQL, that is just works.

Comment: Ahh I understand.  I modified the callback function to output the completed query.  I've replicated it here: https://repl.it/KMmz.  edit:  `db` is just a wrapper for a function that runs `mysql.connect()`, and returns `mysql.query` in a callback, then disconnects.

Comment: Strange... Can you create a snippet for testing?

Comment: If `db` is a wrapper that `connect`s, `query`s, and `disconnect`s, is it possible that you are inadvertently disconnecting before the second run is finished, either by using multiple `db` instances (using multiple connections), or by running in parallel? Does the issue persist if you run it all on once connection?

Can you provide code for `db.executeQuery`?

Comment: Here's an example of the `db.executeQuery` fn: https://repl.it/KO9T/1.  I don't think it's a connection issue, because this function is working normally in other areas.  I'm currently testing locally using one connection to db and a single node instance.